# Google Cloud Platform: are my architectural solutions correct?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I'm trying to make simple application and deploy it on Google Cloud Platform Flexible App Engine, which will contain two main parts:

1. Front end application (simple Web UI based on Java 8 (Spring + Thymeleaf) with OAuth authorization from different external sites)
2. Back end application (monitoring several resources in separate threads, based on logged in users and reacting to their input in a certain way (behavioral changes))

> Initially I was planning to make them as one app, but I think that potentially heavy background processing may cause failures in my front end application part + App Engine docs says that deployed services behave similar to microservice architecture.

My questions are:

1. Do I really need to separate front end from back end, if I need to react to user input as fast as possible? (but delays up to 2 seconds aren't that critical)
2. If I do need to separate them (and I strongly believe that I do) - how to I set up interaction between applications?
3. Each resource must be tracked exactly by one thread on back end - what are the best practices about this? I thought about having a SQL table with a list of acquired resources, but the flaw I see there is if an instance will fail I will need to make some kind of clean up on that table and redetermine which resources are actually acquired.

Comment: What are you using to store the data that you'd need to respond to? Sessions, Memcache, Cloud SQL, something else?

Comment: Cloud SQL. In case where I will use two separate applications for front end and back end, the way I saw it to work - front end writes new / updates existing entity in DB and back end tracks down change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proposed architecture sounds like the right approach in separating the two into different services for the following reasons:

- Can deploy code for each separately, rollback versions separately, and split traffic separately for experiments or phased rollouts.
- Can adjust machine types and memory allocations for each service to better suit its needs. If you're doing work that is memory intensive on the backend, you can adjust that service's settings to allocate more memory per instance.
- Allow each type of service to scale independently based on demands, which should result in better utilization of the services and less waste. This should also lower your overall spending than if you tried to go for a one-sized fits all approach in a single monolithic service.
- You can mix different runtime environments across services. For example, you can mix language runtimes within a project OR you could even mix between standard and flexible environments. Say your front-end code is more cost efficient in standard, designate that service as a standard environment service and your backend as a flexible environment service. Or say you need a customer docker file with Perl in it, you could do that as a flexible environment custom runtime and have your front-end in Java 8.
- You can still share common services like Cloud SQL, PubSub, Cloud Tasks (currently in alpha) or Redis for in memory caching. Your works don't need t reside in App Engine, they could reside in a different product if that better suits your needs.

Overall, you get much better control over your application to split it apart. The biggest benefit likely comes down to optimizing your application for spending only on what you need.

Comment: Well, to sum up your question - I'll get all the benefits of the microservice architecture ;) Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

1. I think that you are likely to be able to deploy everything as an appengine app except if you use some exotic Java libraries that are not whitelisted. It could still be good to deploy it with compute engine for increased configurability and versatility.
2. You can create one front-end instance and one back-end instance in compute engine and divide the resources between them like that. Google's documentation has an example where you can do that.

Comment: On your comment:

 1. Java 8 App Engine doesn't have a whitelist of libraries.
 2. I would like to see a link...